# Why does ModelAndView prompt a NumberFormatException error and not load a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot, modelandview

I'm calculating values (based on input from one JSP) in a method in my Controller class and trying to pass it to another different JSP page using ModelAndView but I'm getting a weird `NumberFormatException` that I think refers to the value at line 249 from error below, `249:    <c:out value="${housepricesList.housePrice}"/>`:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "housePrice"
```

as well as another exception:

```
2018-03-19 12:39:14.439 ERROR 2452 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /houseprice.jsp at line 249

246:     
247: 
248: <c:forEach items="${housepricesList}" var="HousePrice">     
249:    <c:out value="${housepricesList.housePrice}"/>
250:    <c:out value="${housepricesList.number_of_houses}"/>
251: </c:forEach>
252:
```

I'm getting a latitude and longitude from one JSP page, passing it to a method in my Controller where I use the lat & long values to query a database to return house prices within a 1km radius of initial latitude and longitude. I want to pass this returned information (`housePrice` and `number_of_houses`) to another JSP page. However the page won't load and the errors above are displayed in the console.

Controller Class

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/parseHousePrice", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView parseHousePrice(@Valid HousePrice housePriceObject, 
                                    @RequestParam("latitude") double latitude,                                              
                                    @RequestParam("longitude") double longitude) {

    //Initialising HousePriceObject
    housePriceObject = new HousePrice();

    // Passing Lat & Long into method that queries DB
    double housePriceAverage = parseHousePrice.ParseHousePrice(latitude, longitude);

    // This returns the number of houses within the radius
    List<Double> housePriceList = parseHousePrice.getList();
    int housePriceListSize = housePriceList.size();

    // Storing the returned houseprice and number of houses into HousePrice Obeject
    housePriceObject.setHousePrice(housePriceAverage);
    housePriceObject.setNumber_of_houses(housePriceListSize);

    // Debug that shows the query is working correctly 
    // Successfully prints the average house price and number of houses
    System.out.println("The average house price for this area is: " + housePriceAverage + " based on " + housePriceListSize + " property prices in this area");

    // Store the Object into  List
    List<HousePrice> housepricesList = new ArrayList<HousePrice>();
    housepricesList.add(housePriceObject);

     // Add the list to the MAV and pass it to JSP page ("houseprice")
     ModelAndView map = new ModelAndView("houseprice");
        map.addObject("housepricesList", housepricesList);

    return map;
}
```

I have a standard JSP page with the following code that I want to pass the info calculated in the Controller to:

```
<c:forEach items="${housepricesList}" var="HousePrice">     
<c:out value="${housepricesList.housePrice}"/>
<c:out value="${housepricesList.number_of_houses}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

HousePrice entity class

```
@Entity
public class HousePrice {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int housePrice_id;
private double housePrice;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private int number_of_houses;

//constructors

// getters & setters
```

Comment: did you try this way :  map.addObject("housepricesList", housepricesList.toString());

Comment: Hey Sanjay I tried it there and got a new error `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'housePrice' not found on type java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this

```
<c:forEach items="${housepricesList}" var="HousePrice">     
    <c:out value="${HousePrice.housePrice}"/>
    <c:out value="${HousePrice.number_of_houses}"/>
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Yes I did actually try this, and it does stop the errors, however, it still won't load the `houseprice` JSP page. The print debug also still prints in the console. I'm very confused.